# Depending on -sys wrapper library?

Tags: rust

I have a Rust library that is basically some C source, and a bindgen wrapper for it. It has a `build.rs` script that goes into the C source directory, runs `make`, and copies the `.a` static lib to the `$OUT_DIR`. When I run `cargo build`, it all works fine.

However, when I add that library as a dependency in another project, `foo-rs`, it seems that `make` is never getting run. The error I end up with is

```
   Compiling foo-sys v0.1.6
     Running `rustc <LOTS OF STUFF> -L /home/paul/projects/foo-rs/target/build/foo-sys-936b7a25940b4bf0/out -l foo:static`
error: could not find native static library `foo`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?
Could not compile `foo-sys`.
```

Here is the `build.rs` from my `foo-sys` package:

```
use std::old_io::{fs, Command};
use std::os;
use std::old_io::process::InheritFd;

fn main() {
    let manifest_dir = Path::new(os::getenv("PWD").unwrap());
    let out_dir = Path::new(os::getenv("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    let src_dir = manifest_dir.join("src");
    let foo_dir = src_dir.join("foo");
    let foo_lib = foo_dir.join("libfoo.a");

    let mut make = Command::new("make");

    assert!(make.cwd(&foo_dir)
                .arg("release")
                .stdout(InheritFd(1))
                .stderr(InheritFd(2))
                .status()
                .unwrap()
                .success());

    if let Err(_) = fs::copy(&foo_lib, &out_dir.join("libfoo.a")) {
        println!("ERROR COPYING libfoo.a");
    }

    println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-L {} -l foo:static", out_dir.display());
}
```

What confuses me is, if you look at the `rustc` line above, it has the `-L` and `-l foo:static` lines from the end of the `build.rs`, but `libfoo.a` is nowhere to be found.

So somehow, the `make` command isn't being run, but the `build.rs` script is still running?

Comment: No, I have looked in the project dir, as well as my `~/.cargo`, and there is no `.a` lib

Comment: I changed that, and also realized that I was copying the `.a` for no reason...I ended up passing `foo_dir` to `-L` instead of `out_dir`. So, if you want to throw your 2 suggestions in an answer, I will mark it as the accepted one :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `PWD`, try `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR`. The docs say:

> `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` - The directory containing the manifest for the package being built (the package containing the build script). Also note that this is the value of the current working directory of the build script when it starts.

I think there's a fine distinction here - the program is probably *running* in the correct directory, but the `PWD` variable is not updated to match it. This might be a Cargo bug, if it's true.

However, there's no reason to copy libfoo.a around. Instead, use `foo_dir` with -L instead of `out_dir`, simply linking to where ever the library is.